# How to handle x-forwarded-proto with Tomcat and apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, forwarding, internal-load-balancer

I went through a lot of posts related to this issue but I could not find a proper answer. Here is my problem:

I'm trying to enable request logging in Tomcat using AccessLogValve & RemoteIpValve in order to get the IP addresses that originated the request and not the IP from the Loadbalancer.

I have set my Tomacat as follows:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
prefix="access_log." suffix=".txt" 
pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %D"  
resolveHosts="false"/>

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
internalProxies="127\.0\.0\.1| +IP adress from the loadbalancer"
trustedProxies="127\.0\.0\.1| +IP adress from the loadbalancer"
remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
remoteIpProxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"/>
```

As I am using Apache to proxy requests to Tomcat, I added the following to my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !http
RewriteRule !/status http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

But still my logfiles display only the IP from my Loadbalancer.

So I guess I'missing something here and would deeply appreciate a little help.
Thanks a bunch

Comment: Aren't you using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) to do the reverse proxy work?

Comment: @fvu No I'm not. the loadbalancer is external and configured to support X-Forwarded-For. Apache logs contains both IP address from loadbalancer and the original one. However Tomcat logfiles does not.

Comment: You write `remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"` in all-lowercase, I think that's wrong. It could also be helpful to write a basic test servlet to inspect all headers that Tomcat actually sees.